# How to use tap with observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I get user details with flatMap and I also need to get a stream of user image bytes:

```
this.authStore.jwtContainer$.pipe(
    tap(j => {
        foo = this.userService.getUserImageDataUrl(j.userImageObjectKey).subscribe(i => foo = i);
        console.log(j);
    }),
    flatMap(x => this.userService.getUserById(x.userLoginId)))
    .subscribe(z => this.user = z);
```

This code works, but I seem to have a double subscribe situation going on, is there a way to have both calls fire async based on jwtContainer subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to combine all the observables and have them fired parallely:

```
this.authStore.jwtContainer$.pipe(
    flatMap(x =>
        forkJoin([
            this.userService.getUserImageDataUrl(x.userImageObjectKey),
            this.userService.getUserById(x.userLoginId)])))
    .subscribe(([image,user]) => this.user = user);
```

Note that `forkJoin` will have to wait for all its observables to be completed before it can emit the final aggregated results in arrray.